# SDL Input gives "fake-Events" on Startup

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl

I've got a little Problem with SDL:
When starting my Program (on Archlinux 64bit), SDL_event gives me some SDL_KEYDOWN events. The annoying thing with that is, that my Program Quits, when pressing ESCAPE.

Thats the Code:

```
void Input::update() {
    [...]
    while(SDL_PollEvent(event)) {
        if (event != NULL) {
            handleInput();
        }
    }
    // SDL_PumpEvents(); Commented out, because of jrok's suggestion.
    SDL_GetMouseState(&mousex, &mousey);
}
```

And:

```
void Input::handleInput() {
    switch(event->type) {
    case SDL_KEYDOWN:
        setKey(event->key, true);
        break;
    case SDL_KEYUP:
        setKey(event->key, false);
        break;
    case SDL_QUIT:
        setQuit();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

setKey() sets an Element of an bool-Array to the given value (true/false).

Also, its not only the Escape-key. Often the other keys are pressed too.

Comment: Try commenting out `SDL_PumpEvents()`. I don't think you need it, since it's implicitly called by `SDL_PollEvent()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, sorry. SDL has not got any bugs, and the code, i have shown to you is right.

The problem was, that I didn't initialize my boolean Array. So there were Random values left...

That helped:

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_VAL; i++) {
    keys[i] = false;
}
```